# Debian 11 — Too many open files

Tags: linux, debian

Подскажите, как «прибить гвоздями» все лимиты открытых файлов на максимум в Debian 11?

`/etc/security/limits.conf`
`/etc/pam.d/common-session`
— правил (как описано в https://tecadmin.net/increase-open-files-limit-ubuntu/). Все без толку.

```
# ulimit -a
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 31699
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 1018473
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 1024
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) 31699
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited
```

`open files` как было `1024` так и осталось.

Comment: обычно такое поправляют для конкретного приложения. менять все на максимум для всей системы - так себе затея

Comment: @KoVadim это выделенный сервер-молотилка, получающий и обрабатывающий задачи через RabbitMQ... больше он никак «наружу» не смотрит

Comment: в скрипте, который запускает RabbitMQ, просто добавьте ulimit -n 100000 или что то подобное строкой выше перед запуском. Почему не стоит выделять на всё систему? да просто какой то левый процесс может случайно выесть все ресурсы и потом будет не весело